# Unable to import MoviePy

Tags: python, installation, pip, moviepy

I've been trying to install moviepy to my computer without success.

When I try the following command
`import moviepy.editor as me`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy-2.0.0.dev2-py3.8.egg\moviepy\editor.py", line 21, in <module>
    from moviepy.video.io.sliders import sliders
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy-2.0.0.dev2-py3.8.egg\moviepy\video\io\sliders.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2500, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 621, in __getitem__
    plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 257, in switch_backend
    switch_backend(candidate)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 277, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 278, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))
  File "c:\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3agg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import backend_cairo
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_cairo.py", line 38, in <module>
    backend_version = cairo.version
AttributeError: module 'cairocffi' has no attribute 'version'
```

I tried by downloading the .zip file and launching `python setup.py install` instead of using `pip`.

I'm also curious to know if anyone was recently able to successfully the library on a Windows PC. It seems as though there haven't been too many similar questions that have been resolved, so maybe it's no longer possible??

Comment: When I try to reproduce your error  I get `RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'`